# long text in a fixed size scrolable container flutter

Tags: flutter, containers, scrollable, longtext

hello world hope you're well
looking to have a container with a fixed size witch have in it a Text() mean long text more than the size of the container 
Thank you for your help

in flutter

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution thanks to Stonik

Try to add scrollDirection (horizontal)

```
SingleChildScrollView(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Container(
      height: 200,
      child: Text(
          "Long text here which is longer than the container height"))),
```

Default is vertical

or if you want to have with your height then you have to change the order (SingleChildScrollView inside Container)

```
Container(
    height: 200,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Text(
            "Long text here which is longer than the container height"))),
```